# How to have invalid Tcl value from a dict and test against an integer?

Tags: dictionary, tcl

In my Tcl, I have a dictionary lookup that may not exist so I'd like to do something like this:

```
set result [dict exists $values "key"] ? [dict get $values "key"] : "<not present>"
```

However, the ternary operator is evaluating the clause not taken and it fails.

Later I wish to see if the dict value is 10, I tried all these and none work when the result is `"<not present>"`:

```
set test [expr $result == 10]
set test [expr [string is integer $result] && [expr $result == 10]]
set test [expr [string is integer $result] ? [expr $result == 10] : false]
```

What is the Tcl way to test whether the dictionary key exists and its value is equal to 10?

I'd rather not use a numerical value (e.g., `-99`) instead of `"<not present>"` so that I can see when using puts on result that the value was not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just missing the `expr` command, which implements the ternary operator:

```
set result [expr {[dict exists $values key] ? [dict get $values key] : "<not present>"}]
```

Alternatively, just use the more verbose `if`

```
if {[dict exists $values key]} {
    set result [dict get $values key] 
} else {
    set result "<not present>"
}
```

You are missing the braces for expr: see  https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Brace+your+expr-essions

```
set result "<not present>"

set test [expr $result == 10]      ;# => missing operand at _@_
                                   ;# => in expression "_@_<not present> == 10"

set test [expr {$result == 10}]    ;# => 0
```

Comment: In addition, it is idiomatic in Tcl to use the empty string to encode non-existence: `set result [expr {[dict exists $values key] ? [dict get $values key] : ""}]`. This way, the `string is integer` test can be hardened: `string is integer -strict $result`.

Comment: Idiomatic non-existence is indicated by complete absence of the value. And a `NULL` return from quite a few APIs, which is one reason why nulls aren't really Tcl values at all...